# Ordering in a MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with a function in it

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by, group-concat

I want to order the results in a GROUP_CONCAT function. The problem is, that the selection in the GROUP_CONCAT-function is another function, like this (fantasy select):

```
SELECT a.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', b.id, c.name) ORDER BY b.id ASC) AS course
FROM people a, stuff b, courses c
GROUP BY a.id
```

I want to get a result like (ordered by b.id):

```
michael    1:science,2:maths,3:physics
```

but I get:

```
michael    2:maths,1:science,3:physics
```

Does anyone know how I can order by b.id in my group_concat here?

Comment: [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) supports it's own `ORDER BY` clause...  Not knowing what the user defined function is, or does, will not help us to be able to help you.

Comment: It's just like I wrote: the function "concat_ws" within the function "group_concat". I never said it was a user defined function.

Comment: It's unclear how to write a valid solution, as the table structure, content and relationships between the tables is unspecified (i.e. there are no join specifications).

Comment: Because it's not necessary to answer this question.

Comment: @acme Could mark my answer as the correct answer if it is the correct answer? It seems to be very helpful to others.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If anyone cares, I think I found a solution for at least a similar problem.

http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(columnName order by someColumn SEPARATOR '|') from tableName where fieldId = p.id
```

The order by goes in the group_concat BEFORE the separator if there is one.

Comment: Awesome, This one saved my life

Comment: Nice one!!Thanks for sharing

Comment: The same info found [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). 
`SELECT student_name,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
                 ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
 FROM student
 GROUP BY student_name`;

Comment: And if `columnName` and `someColumn` are the same, you can just do a `GROUP_CONCAT(columnName ORDER BY 1 SEPARATOR '|')`.

Comment: This fails to solve the critical problem asked.  How does one order by a Distinct field when that Distinct is done on a function?  "(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', b.id, c.name) ORDER BY b.id ASC)" -- b.id is lost from association after CONCAT_WS(...).  How does one reference that?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is really old, but just now I was looking for an answer and @korny's answer gave me the idea for this:

```
SELECT a.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', b.id, c.name) 
             ORDER BY CONCAT_WS(':', b.id, c.name) ASC) AS course
FROM people a, stuff b, courses c
GROUP BY a.id
```

(And it works for me, if that wasn't clear :-) )

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but I believe this is the same as using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(':', b.id, c.name) ORDER BY 1)`.  Which is much simpler, if it works!

Comment: Yes!  The actually-correct answer!!!  (Of course nobody's doing exactly what the OP is!  We're on this page because we want to know how to reference the results of DISTINCT Func(...) in the Order By, and the answer is you just need to call the Func again.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a standard way to do this. This query works, but I'm afraid it just depends on some implementation detail:

```
SELECT a_name, group_concat(b_id)
FROM (
    SELECT a.name AS a_name, b.id AS b_id
    FROM tbl1 a, tbl2 b
    ORDER BY a.name, b.id) a
GROUP BY a_name
```

Comment: After a little research it seems what I ask is not possible. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 2):

No need for subselects.

```
SELECT people.name, CONCAT_WS(":", stuff.id, courses.name) data
FROM people, stuff, courses
ORDER BY stuff.id, people.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cate_id)
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cate_id) ASC;
```

Comment: I want to order the aggregated elements IN the `GROUP_CONCAT` not the whole results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT generated.name, GROUP_CONCAT(generated.data)
FROM (
    SELECT people.name, CONCAST_WS(":", stuff.id, courses.name) data
    FROM people, stuff, courses
    ORDER BY stuff.id, people.name
) generated
GROUP BY generated.name
```